# Unable to parse image from Json to listview in android

Tags: android, json, android-parser

I am trying to parse the images and text from url to list view.

I succesfully parse names but unable to parse Images. I follow these links....

I am getting bit map value null in image loader class..

I copied the MemoryCache and File Cache classes from the below links...  Is there any mistake in my code?

My Json is: `http://192.185.159.159/~charmmar/raj_spice/webservices/index.php?action=products`
Is any problem for image parsing if json is large?

1. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/
2. http://luchfilip.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show-images-and-texts-in-a-listview/comment-page-1/
3. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

in these links all contained `ImageLoader`, `FileCache`, `MemoryCache` classes but I am unable to parse images... is any special library needed for this?

My class:

```
package com.example.dellizia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RecipesJson extends Helper {

    private String url = com.example.dellizia.Utility.urlpath + "products";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    final String TAG_ID = "id";
    final static String TAG_NAME = "name";
    final static String TAG_IMAGE = "images";
    ListView listview;
    RecipeJsonAdapter adapter;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        PrefEdit("pref__footer", "img_recipe");
        footerBlock();
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(RecipesJson.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            // pdialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            pdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            try {
                String res = JsonFunction.getJSONfromURL(url);
                Log.e("","resvalue--------"+res);
                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(res);

                String id = jsonobj.getString("status");
                Log.e("","id value in parse json--------"+id);
                if (id.equals("1")) {
                    JSONArray userdata = jsonobj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < userdata.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> pdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject obj = userdata.getJSONObject(i);
                        String catid = userdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                        String name = userdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        String image = userdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("images");
                        pdata.put(TAG_ID, catid);
                        Log.e("", "TAG_ID---" + TAG_ID);
                        pdata.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        Log.e("", "TAG_NAME---" + TAG_NAME);
                        Log.e("", "name---" + name);

                        pdata.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
                        Log.e("", "TAG_IMAGE---" + TAG_IMAGE);
                        Log.e("", "image-----------" + image);
                        productList.add(pdata);
                        Log.e("", "product list----" + productList);

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeslist);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new RecipeJsonAdapter(RecipesJson.this, productList);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

My adapter class:

```
package com.example.dellizia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

    import com.example.androidhive.ImageLoader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class RecipeJsonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

        public RecipeJsonAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            activity = a;
            data=d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipeitems, null);

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
            //TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
            //TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
            ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.recipeimage); // thumb image

            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song = data.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview
            Log.e("","names values ------------"+song.get(RecipesJson.TAG_NAME));

            title.setText(song.get(RecipesJson.TAG_NAME));
            //artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
           // duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
            Log.e("","images values ------------"+song.get(RecipesJson.TAG_IMAGE));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(RecipesJson.TAG_IMAGE), thumb_image);
            return vi;
        }
    }
```

This is my link for all classes.. http://ge.tt/8keNUh62?c. In this link all my used classes are available.

Please help!

Comment: you can use the LazyList library from this [link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: Maybe the link help you: www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: Please check [this example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/)